# Combined standard error function in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, standard-error

Basically, I have several experiments (`SITE`s) spanning over the course of several years, each year with its own mean and standard error (based on several replicates each), and I want to calculate the grand mean and standard error for each `SITE`. The grand mean seems fairly straight-forward (average the means?) but the grand standard error is less intuitive for me. How can I create a function to calculate the grand SE to use with dplyr? A simplified version of my data is below:

```
> print(tbl_df(df), n=40)
Source: local data frame [76 x 8]

            SITE YEAR Myc  CO2     N      ANPP   ANPP.se nyears
1    Placerville 1991 ECM elev  Nlow    0.8100   0.14000      3
2    Placerville 1991 ECM  amb  Nlow    0.5400   0.07000      3
3    Placerville 1992 ECM elev  Nlow   53.1200  11.83000      3
4    Placerville 1992 ECM  amb  Nlow   26.9000   3.28000      3
5    Placerville 1993 ECM elev  Nlow 1068.3000 183.80000      3
6    Placerville 1993 ECM  amb  Nlow  619.0000 118.90000      3
7    Placerville 1991 ECM elev Nhigh    1.5700   0.26000      3
8    Placerville 1991 ECM  amb Nhigh    1.2800   0.17000      3
9    Placerville 1992 ECM elev Nhigh   75.4300  10.29000      3
10   Placerville 1992 ECM  amb Nhigh   56.2700   7.34000      3
11   Placerville 1993 ECM elev Nhigh 2118.9000 696.10000      3
12   Placerville 1993 ECM  amb Nhigh 1235.8000 260.40000      3
13   Jasper_FACE 1999  AM  amb  Nlow  386.3371  34.92557      5
14   Jasper_FACE 2000  AM  amb  Nlow  551.2848 124.64485      5
15   Jasper_FACE 2001  AM  amb  Nlow  552.1139  56.65156      5
16   Jasper_FACE 2002  AM  amb  Nlow  410.7524  27.64737      5
17   Jasper_FACE 2003  AM  amb  Nlow  503.6037  57.68552      5
18   Jasper_FACE 1999  AM  amb Nhigh  680.8551  67.99471      5
19   Jasper_FACE 2000  AM  amb Nhigh  480.5723  33.52034      5
20   Jasper_FACE 2001  AM  amb Nhigh  744.5131 125.32998      5
21   Jasper_FACE 2002  AM  amb Nhigh  603.6049  62.19760      5
22   Jasper_FACE 2003  AM  amb Nhigh  711.5993 142.04351      5
23   Jasper_FACE 1999  AM elev  Nlow  488.5912  61.47564      5
24   Jasper_FACE 2000  AM elev  Nlow  406.2773  32.90862      5
25   Jasper_FACE 2001  AM elev  Nlow  543.3647  55.28956      5
26   Jasper_FACE 2002  AM elev  Nlow  480.7108  65.24701      5
27   Jasper_FACE 2003  AM elev  Nlow  473.6844  52.01606      5
28   Jasper_FACE 1999  AM elev Nhigh  638.0252  58.34743      5
29   Jasper_FACE 2000  AM elev Nhigh  505.2054 171.62024      5
30   Jasper_FACE 2001  AM elev Nhigh  655.1032 130.01279      5
31   Jasper_FACE 2002  AM elev Nhigh  677.7134  98.84845      5
32   Jasper_FACE 2003  AM elev Nhigh  926.3433 143.26525      5
33 Merrit_Island 1997 ECM  amb  Nlow  137.0940  22.20700      4
34 Merrit_Island 1998 ECM  amb  Nlow  296.4870  53.32100      4
35 Merrit_Island 1999 ECM  amb  Nlow  350.9470  57.85000      4
36 Merrit_Island 2000 ECM  amb  Nlow  494.6030  66.70200      4
37 Merrit_Island 1997 ECM elev  Nlow  203.7970  26.63300      4
38 Merrit_Island 1998 ECM elev  Nlow  467.8080  62.33200      4
39 Merrit_Island 1999 ECM elev  Nlow  586.8180  91.26500      4
40 Merrit_Island 2000 ECM elev  Nlow  866.3460 126.77000      4
```

I would need to implement a function in R to specify a function in dplyr to calculate grand mean and grand se for each group, like this:

```
tempSE <- df %>% group_by(SITE,CO2,N,nyears) %>% 
  summarise(ANPP=mean(ANPP),
  SD=grand.sd(ANPP.se))
```

EDIT: In case your answer involves an equation that includes sample size: on the dataset, the column `nyears`is the number of years, which is the number of measurements per `SITE` and `CO2`treatment I need to average for. On the other hand, within each year, each `ANPP`mean and `ANPP.se`is based on a number of replicates or plots, which is the sample size contained in SE, but not specified in any column. Which of these two types of sample size is the one I need?

Thanks

Comment: `variance of A+B=variance of A+variance of B+ co-variance of A and B` ?.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: @Legalizelt n is different among SITEs, but the same between CO2 treatments within SITEs. I don’t know how to calculate weighted averages

Comment: “n”=sample size, sorry

Comment: I don’t know if the sample size I need to weight is the number of replicates per treatment or the number of years with data per treatment...

Comment: I mean, is the sample size the one that was originally used to calculate mean and SE, or the new one based on the number of years per site?

Comment: This sounds like a statistics advice more than a programming one. Can you jot down the full formula you want to use?

Comment: Maybe I missed something but what about: `dat %>% group_by(SITE) %>% mutate(Me = mean(ANPP), Sd = sd(ANPP.se))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we don't know anything about the sample sizes, it is impossible to calculate the grand mean or the grand standard error. Here is a small example: Coin flipping, counting "heads" as 1 and "tails" as 0. The mean of our first sample is 0.45, the mean of the second sample is 0.65. If the two samples have the same size, the grand mean is 0.55. But if the sample sizes are 900 and 100, respectively, we have 405+65 "heads", so the grand mean 0.47.
If the the sample sizes are known, the grand mean can be computed as follows:

1. Multiply each individual mean by the corresponding sample size.
2. Sum up these numbers,
3. Divide that sum by the sum of the individual sample sizes.

To compute the standard error, proceed as follows:

1. Multiply the square of each individual standard error by the corresponding sample size.
2. To each of these numbers, add the square of the corresponding mean.
3. Multiply each of theses numbers by the corresponding sample size. (These are the sums of the squares of the sampled values.)
4. Sum up these numbers. (Now we have the sum of all the squares.)
5. Divide that sum by the sum of the individual sample sizes. (This gives the mean of the squares.)
6. Subtract the square of the grand mean. (-> Variance)
7. Take the square root of that number. (-> Standard deviation)
8. Divide that number by the square root of the sum of the individual sample sizes.

Writing an R function for this should be straightforward. But we need the sample sizes, at least up to a common factor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clarifies the equation. However, I have one big question I don’t fully understand: I can see you may refer to two different sample sizes: i) within each SITE, YEAR and CO2 treatment each sample mean and SE was made out of a few replicates, so the number of replicates per treatment is one potential sample size; ii) if I compute the grand mean and SE for each SITE and CO2 treatment the sample size would be the number of years, for instance, for the SITE “Merrit_Island” there are 4 years of measurements, hence the sample size is 4. Which sample size would you use?

Comment: Basically the number of replicates is the sample size. If the number of replicates per year is a constant, the sample size is proportional to the number of years and then we can replace the sample sizes by number of years. This is because in the computations any common factor of the sample sizes cancels out. But if the number of replicates per year is not a constant, this simplification is not possible.

Comment: Following your advice:  `tempSESum <- tempSE %>% group_by(id,SITE,Myc,CO2,N,nyears) %>% 
  summarise(ANPP.mean=mean(ANPP),
            sumSquares= sum(squares),sumN=sum(nyears)) %>% 
  mutate (meanSquares=(sumSquares/sumN), var= meanSquares - (ANPP.mean)^2,
          SEII=sqrt(var))`

Comment: Does it look OK? The resulting grand SE look too high based on the magnitude of SE of outcomes with similar mean values

Comment: The reason for the high variance is, that the means are not very similar. Suppose you have two samples and each of them is constant. Then each of them has variance 0. But if the constant value of the first sample is +100 and that of the second one is -100, the grand variance is very high, because the distance between the values +/-100 and the grand mean 0 is very high.

Comment: So I assume you have checked my calculations and think they are OK? Do you know any source where I can see these equations so I can check everything is correct and cite it?

Comment: Maybe I confounded standard deviation with standard error, but the two differ from each other only by the square root of the sample size. So far the procedure in my answer described how to compute the grand standard deviation, given the standard deviations of several samples. So all one has to do is multiplication of each of the given standard errors by the square root of the corresponding sample size, then computation of the grand standard deviation as described so far, and finally devision by the total sample size. I added the first and the last step into my answer.

Comment: You can look up the formula used for example on Wikipedia (-> Standard error).

Comment: That’s what I thought, SD instead of SE. Modified accordingly: `tempSE$squares <- (((tempSE$ANPP.se)^2)*tempSE$rep + (tempSE$ANPP)^2)* tempSE$rep 
tempSESum <- tempSE %>% group_by(id,SITE,Myc,CO2,N,rep) %>% 
  summarise(ANPP.mean=mean(ANPP),
            sumSquares= sum(squares),sumN=sum(rep)) %>% 
  mutate (meanSquares=(sumSquares/sumN), var= meanSquares - (ANPP.mean)^2,
          SD=sqrt(var), SE=SD/sqrt(sumN))`